ESLint custom rule, prevent import except index
I have some components in /components/business/my-component
This folder is organized like that:

hooks/useHook.ts
layout/Layout.tsx
index.tsx

I want to do a rule to only accept import of index.tsx.
Example: importing userHook or Layout.tsx should throw an error
I tried :
    {
        "rules": {    
            "no-restricted-imports": [
                "error",
                {
                    "patterns": [
                        "*/components/business/**", // Block all imports from any "business" directory.
                        "!*/components/business/**/index" // Allow only index.tsx inside business directories.
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

But it's not working
Example imports (expectation):
 import Foo from '@/components/business/myComponent/index' // must pass
 import { Layout } from '@/components/business/myComponent/Layout' // must fail


Perhaps create your own custom rule?
